# 在宅勤務しているのにずっと寝にいきたいです。

Tags: particles

Does this sound natural?
Thank you for your kind answer in advance.

Comment: I'd like to know what you wanna mean. What's the point of "のに"? The answer depends on it. Do you feel sleepy when you work at office, chill at home and work at home? You are using "寝に行く"; Do you want to go home and sleep when you work at office?

Comment: I'd like to say: Despite working at home, I always want to sleep. (because I feel sleepy all the time at home)

Comment: @Alessandro 寝に行きたい means you want to go *somewhere in order to* sleep. The English 'go to sleep' is basically just 寝る

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand what you are trying to say.
Like it says in the comments you don't literally say "go to sleep" in Japanese, you just say 寝る so if you want to sleep it's 寝たい or if you want to keep sleeping you could say 寝ていたい
Maybe you want to say
在宅勤務なのにずっと寝ていたい

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!